# where to locate uninstal file

Tags: linux, netbeans, linux-mint

I have linux Mint 16 and I have installed netbeans by apt-get install netbeans and I saw after installation that is the version 7.0.1 but I’d like to have the 7.4 version. I’d like to installant version 7.0.1 but I don't find the uninstall.sh file and I don't know where the program is install.

I hope you can help me and note that I begin in Linux

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 apt-get remove packagename
```

will remove the binaries, but not the configuration or data files of the package packagename. It will also leave dependencies installed with it on installation time untouched.

```
apt-get remove --purge packagename
```

will remove about everything regarding the package packagename, but not the dependencies installed with it on installation. Both commands are equivalent.